# MacOS apps beta distribution via Crashlytics / Fabric

Tags: ios, macos, google-fabric

How to distribute my macOS Apps via Fabric? When i archive my macOS build it doesn't show up in Fabric. There's no official documentation, only "it works exactly the same as for iOS".

Comment: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. MacOS apps currently cannot be distributed through Beta, only [iOS, Android and Unity apps](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/overview.html) can be distributed through Beta.

Comment: Why not? Are there any plans to support it?

Comment: It's not on our roadmap to add support for macOS distribution through Beta.

Comment: too bad. It's such a great service otherwise. 